# Get table data from with post method

Tags: php, jquery, http-post

I've been working in a project where I need to dynamically fill a table according with what I select from two combobox, so the problem is that I need to take those values to save them on the database but I can't find a way to do this.

The code when I press the button:

```
 <input type="button" name="btnAgregarPrograma" value="Agregar" onClick="addRow()"/>



function addRow()
{
var dep = $("#cbxDependencia").val();
var pro = $("#cbxPrograma").val();
if(dep == 0 || pro == 0)
    alert('Debe seleccionar una dependencia y un programa para poder agregarlos'); //Traslation: you must select a dependency and a program to continue
else
{
    $.get("funciones/agregarProDep.php",{pro: pro},
        function(resultado)
        {
            if(resultado == false)
            {
                alert("Error");
            }
            else
            {
                $("#table_depProg").attr("disabled",false);
                var row = $("<tr>" + resultado + "</tr>");
                $('#table_depProg').append(row);            
            }
        }
    );
}
}
```

As you can see, the code above calls a php file with the next code

```
<?php
include("funciones.php");
$pro = 0;
$programas = agregarProgramaDependencia($_GET["pro"]);

foreach($programas as $fila)
{
echo ("
        <td id=".$fila['idPrograma'].">".$fila['Nombre']."</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Eliminar' onclick='borrarFila(this)'</td>
      ");
}
?>
```

That's the way I fill the table, but now I just can't find a way to get the contained data when I submit the page to get and save the data, I would apreciate any help.

I tried to explain the best I could, if something is not clear just let me know and I will answer back with a better explanation.

Comment: to get data submitted from a page you need a from, which i don't see in the ode above

Comment: @Dagon - You _don't_ need a form element when using Ajax. (I'm assuming your "from" was a typo that should've been "form".) Aaron - Your question title and tags say "post" but your code does a "get" - is that on purpose?

Comment: What is the result/status that is returned? Check the `network tab` within your favorite `web inspector`.

Comment: Sorry, the subjetct was going to be "Get table data with post method" I don't know why I wrote "from", sorry... and about the "get" part, yes, i use it to fill the table, but I actually need a way to collect the data of the filled table using the post method because I first need to submit the page... I'm kinda lost here, I'm still new with PHP and jquery :/
edit: I'm using a form, just I didn't copy the code, but is using the "post" method.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into the same thing and here is what I did.

1. Created a `DataRow` object that contained the fields of each row
2. Iterated through the table's rows (skipping the header) and stored each row in a `DataRow` and pushed it onto an Array.
3. Used `JSON.Stringify` to convert the Array to JSON
4. Stored the JSON in a `<input type="hidden">` so it would get POSTed.

Here is the HTML example:

```
<table border="2px solid black">   
    <tr id="header-row">
            <th>Dx Code</th>
            <th>Dx Date</th>
            <th>OnSet Or Ex</th>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3022</td> 
        <td>1/1/2014</td>
        <td>ONSET</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>V9099</td> 
        <td>1/21/2014</td>
        <td>EX</td>
   </tr>  
   <tr>
        <td>1199</td> 
        <td>1/31/2014</td>
        <td>ONSET</td>
   </tr>           
</table>

<br />
<input type="button" value = "Submit" id="out">
```

JavaScript:

```
// object to hold your data
function dataRow(value1,value2,value3) {
    this.dxCode = value1;
    this.dxDate = value2;
    this.dxType = value3;
}

$('#out').click(function(){   

    // create array to hold your data
    var dataArray = new Array();

    // iterate through rows of table
    // * Start from '2' to skip the header row *
    for(var i = 2; i <= $("table tr").length; i++){
            // create object and push to array
            dataArray.push(    
                new dataRow(
                    $("table tr:nth-child(" + i + ") td").eq(0).html(),
                    $("table tr:nth-child(" + i + ") td").eq(1).html(),
                    $("table tr:nth-child(" + i + ") td").eq(2).html())
            );
    }

    var sJson = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
    alert(sJson);
})
```

Finally, JSFiddle to see it: http://jsfiddle.net/leisenstein/vy3ux/